# Swift Firebase authentication not working when in another class

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am attempting a project just for fun, I would like to use Firebase. I made a class to user for user related things. I was testing the signing up function and when it is within a class it first yields false then yields true. But when I do not place this in a separate class and place it directly in the view controller it yields true and performs the segue as indicated. Due to I not knowing how to explain this best I will show below which code works and which does not.

Firebase embedded in a class:

```
    import Foundation
import Firebase
class Account  {

    var email: String
    var password: String
 init(email: String, password: String) {
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    }
   func createAccount ()-> Bool{
        var made = false
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if (error == nil) {
                print("Registration Successful")
                made = true

            }else{

                print(error!)
                made = false
            }
        }
        print("this is\(made)")
     return made

    }
```

button code:

```
@IBAction func signUpButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
signUpEmail = emailTextField.text!
signUpPassword = passwordTextField.text!
let signUp = Account(email: signUpEmail, password: signUpPassword);
let signUpOccur = signUp.createAccount()
if( signUpOccur == true){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpToHome", sender: self)
}else{
  print(signUpOccur)
}}
```

////this yields: "this is false" then "Registration Successful" then "this is true" but does not perform the Segue due to first yielding false I assume

code that works as desired:

```
 signUpEmail = emailTextField.text!
        signUpPassword = passwordTextField.text!
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: signUpEmail, password: signUpPassword) { (user, error) in
            if (error == nil) {
                print("Registration Successful")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpTohome", sender: self)
      }else{

                print(error!)
             }
        }
```

Is it possible to place thing within a class and function or would it be best to just place it within the button the way it works? Or is there something I am doing wrong?

Thank you for all feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `createUser` method is asynchronous. You are returning `made` from your function before `createUser` finishes.

`func createAccount()-> Bool {...}`

should be

`func createAccount(completion: (Bool)->Void) {...}`

And then when the Firebase Auth call to createUser completes, you call `completion(made)`.

You will need to read up on asynchronous calls in programming and closures in swift to understand better. You can start with something like [this article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/managing-async-code-in-swift-d7be44cae89f).